# JBoss Fuse with microservises

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, microservices, jbossfuse

I am a **beginner** , I have a task about j Boss fuse I spent the last week trying to learn about it but still confused with it

I have several question :

1- how j boss fuse is different from camel with real example please?
2- how j boss fuse is useful for microservices ?
3- difference between j boss fuse and j boss fuse EAP ?
4- how to use j boss fuse with spring boot if that is possible and if their is a better option ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You'll do better with a single, focused question.

1- how j boss fuse is different from camel with real example please?

[Fuse](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/fuse) is a Red Hat/JBOSS offering for service integration.  Camel is part of the implementation, like the documentation says.

2- how j boss fuse is useful for microservices ?

It might be useful if you are committed to using JBOSS, but I think there are other alternatives: Mule Soft, API gateways, etc.  I would rather leave JBOSS out of it and deploy Spring Boot without it.  Why would you need JBOSS when you're using Spring Boot?  What benefit is it giving you?  That's the whole point of Spring/Spring Boot: getting away from Java EE.

3- difference between j boss fuse and j boss fuse EAP ?

[EAP](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform) stands for "Enterprise Application Platform".  That's the Java EE app server that's been around for a long time.  You could deploy your microservices on JBOSS EAP instances and integrate them together using Fuse.

4- how to use j boss fuse with spring boot if that is possible and if their is a better option ?

You would use Spring Boot to implement your micro services, deploy them as WAR files on JBOSS EAP, and integrate them using Fuse.

Yes, there are better options.  I would recommend Spring Boot without JBOSS.  No need for a Java EE app server; deploy them as executable JAR files running on a JVM.  I would prefer to stay away from Red Hat and deploy on Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Thank you ...... so as you say it is better to build microservices with spring boot than jboss ...  
  is it possible to use camel with microservices as a gateway ??

Comment: To be precise, I'd say that you are developing micro services in Spring Boot either way.  You are debating a choice whether or not to deploy and integrate using JBOSS and Fuse or something else.

Comment: You certainly can deploy with JBOSS and Fuse.  My personal preference is to avoid them.  I'm using Pivotal Cloud Foundry.  I think the support for Spring Boot is better there.

Answer (score 0):

[Red Hat Fuse](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/fuse) (7.7) includes [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/getting-started.html) (2.23.2) as its central component and supports different runtimes: Karaf, EAP and SpringBoot/SpringBoot2.

To use it with SpringBoot, you just need to import the BOM in your project `pom.xml` and you will get a tested set of Camel components along with their dependecies, that you can use to create your microservices.

Fuse is built from Open Source software, so you can run SpringBoot and then add Camel on top of it, but you won't have a tried and tested distribution of these libraries and a dedicated support for it. There is also the possibility to run [Camel standalone](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/main.html), without any runtime.